# Expandable GCM push `notification` from server side

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, push, expand

First of all, I have searched for a solution to my problem, but found none. Maybe it's too obvious or I am bad at searching. If it's so I am sorry.

**Problem:**

When sending GCM push notifications from server to mobile and supporting iOS, I must send a `notification` tag. This `notification` tag means the android system does not awake my application to handle the notification and does it itself. Even if I send `data` tag too.

My problem is when I try to make the app expandable. I know how to make it from code, but don't know how to set it from server side like the icon or color.

**Question:**

Is it any way to set notification as expandable (big view style) from server? If it's not, can I force the system to awaken my app to handle the notification?

Comment: what do you mean by Expandable?

Comment: It can be expanded when pressing (or two finger pressing) and dragging to show, for example, more text.

Comment: why dont you just create the notification in the app when you get the push? dont use the notification tag in the payload and you get the push at anytime when you just have the data tag

Comment: The problem with that is that the notification tag is needed for iOS compatibility. As far as I know, the only way to assure the notification shows on an iOS device is setting this tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With iOS there is a separate tag you need to have in your payload to so that you can get what you want on both platforms

if you look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html) you will see there is a tag `content-available` and when you use this tag it acts similar to how adding only the data tag in android would, you get the push in background vi the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` in your app delegate class.

There is where you would create the notification manually like you would on android

Comment: As far as I know, doing so would mean iOS apps could not receive the notification when the app is killed. Is it true?

I am not an iOS developer, so I may be wrong.

Comment: that is not correct you get push notifications anytime, have your ios developer read the documentation I linked and it tell you what you have to change